# How can i compile Python 3.8.2 for MIPS64 platform

Tags: python-3.x

How to compile Python 3.8.2 for mips64.
I have used this command:

```
root@Giri:/home/subhra/Downloads/Python-3.8.2# ./configure --host=mips --build=x86
```

**Output:**

```
checking build system type... x86-unknown-none
checking host system type... mips-unknown-elf
checking for python3.8... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for python interpreter for cross build... configure: error: python3.8 interpreter not found
------------------
Please suggest me what is the right command to cross compile for MIPS64
```